# Getting max for foreign key rails active record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am struggling with Rails' ActiveRecord to achieve the following query.

My schema is more or less like this:

I have a table `quests`, which is related to `solutions` with a one-to-many relation (ie. `quest has_many solutions` and `solution belongs_to quest`).

`solutions` is also related to `guilds` by a one-to-many (ie. `guild has_many solutions` and `solution belongs_to guild`).

`solutions` has a `score` integer column.

What I want is to get the solutions with the best score of each guild for a given quest.
In SQL I think I would write something like this.

```
SELECT quests.id, solutions.*, max(solutions.score) 
FROM quests 
INNER JOIN solutions ON solutions.quest_id = quests.id 
WHERE quests.id IN (1, 2, 3 or whatever I want to fetch)
GROUP BY solutions.guild_id, quests.id;
```

As I have many of these to show on a single page, I am trying to get this working as a relation in my `Quest` class so that I can prefetch these with something like `Quest.includes(:best_solutions).limit(40)`

Here is what I have tried (inside the `Quest` model).

```
has_many :best_solutions,
       -> { select('solutions.*, max(solutions.score)')
           .group('solutions.guild_id', 'solutions.quest_id')
           .readonly },
       class_name: 'Solution',
       foreign_key: 'quest_id'
```

which I felt quite happy about when I tried `Quest.first.best_solutions`, which yielded:

```
SELECT solutions.*, max(solutions.score) 
FROM "solutions" 
INNER JOIN "quests" 
ON "quests"."id" = "solutions"."quest_id" 
WHERE "solutions"."quest_id" = ? 
GROUP BY solutions.guild_id, quests.id
```

However, when I tried to combine that with `includes`, the query it gives me has just nothing to do with what I am trying to get. For example, `Quest.includes(:best_solutions).load` yielded

```
SELECT solutions.*, max(solutions.score) 
FROM "solutions" 
WHERE "solutions"."quest_id" IN (1, 2......)
```

Could someone explain me what I am missing here.

Thank you.